# Sounds with pygame can't be opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am just trying to do this really simple thing where I want to play two different sound files depending on a touch sensor.
The problem that I currently have is that I cannot even play one of them without anything else, because 'the files cannot be opened'.

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 12, 512)
pygame.init

slowbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/slowbeat.wav')
slowbeat.set_volume(.4);

fastbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/fastbeat.wav')
fastbeat.set_volume(.4);

slowbeat.play()
```

The traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/a.py", line 11, in
>    slowbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('slowbeat.wav') pygame.error:
>   Unable to open file 'slowbeat.wav'

Comment: Please post the complete error message (traceback). It could be a problem with the paths or filenames. Double-check if they are correct. Also, you forgot the parentheses behind `pygame.init`.

Comment: ohh thankss and here is the whole error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/a.py", line 11, in <module>
    slowbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('slowbeat.wav')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'slowbeat.wav'

Comment: Adding the missing parentheses fixed it, right? You have to call this function to initialize all pygame modules, otherwise some things won't work correctly. You usually also have to open a pygame window in order to play sounds and music. If you don't want to open a window, you can just call `pygame.mixer.init()` before `pygame.init()`.

Comment: hmm maybe I am doing something wrong but the same error message still pops up :(

Comment: Could it be that it has something to do with my file ?

Comment: Are the filenames and paths correct? Could you upload one of the wav files?

Comment: How could I possibly do that? Should I just send you a link ?

Comment: I will try it now with an ogg file, maybe that works!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the missing parentheses behind `pygame.init()` should fix the problem (unless something is wrong with the path and filenames). You have to call this function to initialize all pygame modules, otherwise some things won't work correctly. You usually also have to open a pygame window in order to play sounds and music.

If you don't want to open a window, you can just call `pygame.mixer.init()` before or instead of `pygame.init()`.

Comment: Oh okay, so I guess i will check that again... Although I thought that .wav files shouldn't be a problem? And also I copied the exact same path as shown in the descriptions of the files, but I will double check that now! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hmm, then maybe the files were corrupted.